# Problem installing WPT manifest using wevtutil

Tags: windows, performance, xperf

I'm trying to add performance counters and custom events to a piece of software, so that I can view these using Windows Performance Toolkit programs such as XPerf and GPUView.
  I am going to refrain, using all my powers of restraint, from launching into a cathartic rant regarding the state of the documentation for the software and the time I've now wasted trying to tease clues from the web. I'm going to describe how I got to where I am now, just in case this is of use to other lost souls.

So far, I've gathered that I have to write an Event manifest for my performance counters and events. You can do this by hand or by using a tool called '**ecmangen.exe**'. The documentation for that program gives a nice step by step guide for event creating manifests but doesn't explain how to integrate these with your code.

The next step, as far as I can work out, is to use two cryptic command line applications '**MC.exe**' and '**CTRPP.exe**'. These seem to generate C or C# headers, source and resource files for adding event and counter instrumentation to your code, respectively.
  Next, you have to build your code (look at the samples in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\winbase\Eventing') and then we come to where I'm currently stuck: the correct use of the next cryptic tool '**wevtutil.exe**'

This tool needs two things: the binary (exe or DLL) that you've compiled with those resources in it and the manifest file you used to generate those resources. The trouble I'm having is that it's *very* picky about where the binary file is and I've been unable to determine the form of this pickiness. Incantations and goat sacrifices have yielded no results.

If I have a path defined in the 'resourceFileName' field of the 'provider' tag in the manifest file such as 'c:\MYDIR\TEd.exe' then it is fine. If, however, I put the same exe in a different folder (one that failed was C:\tw\TEd.exe), it complains.

The error message given is **'Warning: Publisher TEd-Event-Provider resources are not accessible.'** but no more explanation as to why, or where it tried to look.

So, am I going about adding instrumentation in the wrong way, is there already a guide that explains all the gotchas and what is the nature of 'wevtutil.exe's strange selectivity towards directory names.

Thanks in advance,

Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had exactly the same message, and struggled for an hour to resolve it, before I had a brainwave and read the error msg ;-).

The solution to my problem was simply to add the ".rc" file to my project, and then re-build.  Looking back it is fairly obvious, but it had me stumped for a while.

Hope this helps.

---

Edit - 4th Feb
Ok, not too sure if I know what your problem is, but the following batch script is how I did it all.  Good luck.

```
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------
rem Do all of this from the project directory

rem -------------------------------------------------------------------
rem Generate Header and Resource - remove the ReadOnly attrib to "help" it along
attrib -r MyModuleTracing.h
mc.exe -um MyModuleTracing.xml
rem This generates MyModuleTracing.h and MyModuleTracing.rc, add both to your project

rem -------------------------------------------------------------------
rem ** Now build the project **
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------

rem Register MyModule Tracing with the system
if exist MyModuleTracing.xml (
  wevtutil um MyModuleTracing.xml

  copy MyModuleTracing.xml Release
  cd Release
  copy MyModule.dll %SystemRoot%\System32
  wevtutil im MyModuleTracing.xml
)

rem -------------------------------------------------------------------
rem Do a capture, and also export the results to an XML file.
xperf -start MyModuleSession -on [REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_GUID] -f MyModuleSession.etl
xperf -on base -f Kernel.etl

rem Run the app, wait until exit, and then stop the capture
start /wait MyModule.exe

xperf -stop
xperf -stop MyModuleSession
xperf -merge MyModuleSession.etl Kernel.etl MyModuleSessionMerged.etl

tracerpt MyModuleSessionMerged.etl -o MyModuleSessionMerged.xml -of XML
```

Comment: Thanks Rich, I'll try that out tomorrow.

Comment: I've got all of mine working now, so if you still can't get yours working, let me know and I'll describe what I've done.

Comment: Ah, still no dice. I was already adding the '.rc' files, at least the two named 'XXXXX_manifest.rc' and 'XXXXX_profile_events.rc'.

Comment: What's stumping me is the fact that it works if the output dir is in one place but not in another place.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - as best I can tell, there's a directory length limit on wevtutil. When I installed the file from a directory with a shorter path, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else comes across this, you can actually get things working from an arbitrary directory:

Add USER Read&Execute privs to a directory containing or above your project:

> `icacls` *projectdir* `/grant BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(RX)`

Then installing the manifest should work with no errors:

> `wevtutil im` *yourmanifest.man* `/rf:`*c:\full\path\to\yourprogram.exe* `/mf:`*c:\full\path\to\yourprogram.exe*