# Event Tracing for Windows(ETW): wevtutil erratic behaviour based on resource's file path

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, etw

Alright, I asked this question on microsoft forums and was surprised by their action.

This is the question http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/6c2354ae-f9f6-423f-bf91-a34b40e20fa1:

I've also reposted it here with some more information.

> This post
>   [Problem installing WPT manifest using wevtutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679445/problem-installing-wpt-manifest-using-wevtutil)
>   suggested that wevtutil has a restriction on the size of the
>   resourcefileName attribute in the manifest.
>
> I thought this must not be, but unfortunately it is!
>
> I am wondering why there would be such a restriction.
>
> Here's what I have done. I have a solution with a fairly moderate path
>   depth (e.g. C:\users\\\
>
> If I point the resourceFileName and messageFileName(in the manifest
>   file which is  needed to set up the event tracing.  See here
>   :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd996930(v=vs.85).aspx)
>   to the exe in it's original path (which  is of the above format)  I
>   get a warning :
>
> ```
> resources are not accessible.
> ```
>
> If I set the exe's path to something like C:\temp\publisher.exe and
>   then manually copy
>
> the exe from the solution output directory to the C:\temp folder,
>   everything works fine.
>
> PS: Also, the exe has to have the right permissions for
>   accessibility.
>
> Now, my question is, why this unnecessary restriction on the file
>   path? If this is the  way this supposedly powerful api is written that
>   it cannot handle filepaths more than a certain length, then I am sorry
>   to say it's been programmed very poorly. Ironically, it has   a lot of
>   features which I would love to use in my application.
>       That being, said, IS there any specific option with the resourceFileName and  messageFileName attributes that could change
>   this behaviour? The msdn does not say anything about it. Or am I
>   missing something?

First off, if anyone has found a workaround to install an event publisher from ANY path, could you please enlighten me?

Second, microsoft's response. Without even reading my question properly, a moderator moved my question to the Windows Server thread( he guessed  this with the word resourceFileName which apparently might have some relation to Windows Server.) I have always been unhappy with Microsoft, but this is annoying!

Comment: What exactly is the path that fails?  I'm guessing it's something silly like exceeding MAX_PATH or containing spaces.

Comment: Well, the path fails with and without spaces. e.g. C:\Users\richardm\EventTest\EventTest.exe fails but C:\temp\EventTest.exe doesn't.